# Generics in C#, Dictionary<TKey,TValue>

Tags: c#, generics

I started reading C# in depth. Now I'm in the journey of Generics. I came across the first example of Generics in this book as:

```
static Dictionary<string,int> CountWords(string text)
{
   Dictionary<string,int> frequencies;
   frequencies = new Dictionary<string,int>();
   ... //other code goes here..
```

And after this code, author says that:

```
The CountWords method first creates an empty map from string to int
```

This looks vague to me, as a novice in C#, what the author is trying to mean `string to int`(in the above statement)? I'm bit confused with this line.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe @Jon Skeet wants to answer himself ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter : oh ya, I guess he might be answering some other C# questions, right now ;)

Comment: I think the other answers have covered it now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lets say we want to count the words in a paragraph:

> I started reading C# in depth. Now I am in the journey of Generics. 
>   I came across the first example of Generics in this book as

In order to count the words, you'll need some data structure that will be able to store a number of occurrences for each of the words, that will basically attach a number to a string, like

> I - 3 times
>   in - 3 times
>   Generics - 2 times
>   etc...

that structure maps a string to an integer, and in C# Generics, that structure is a `Dictionary<string,int>`

BTW, if you are a C# beginner, i would recommend against C# in depth, which, while being a great book, assumes a quite advanced reader.

Comment: Well, i'm enjoying with that book :) and for reference i have C# in nutshell.. I can cope up! :)

Answer (score 1):

He means that `string` is your key and `int` is the value paired with the key.

Answer (score 1):

`Dictionary<string,int>` maps a `string` key (or lookup) to an `int` value.

Answer (score 1):

Consider `Dictionary<string,int> frequencies`.
When you try to add an item you use (for example)

```
frequencies.Add("key3", 3)
```

When you add another item you cannot repeat "key3", because in `Dictionary` that's a unique key; so you create a "map" because you are sure you have unique keys and you can recall values using their key: `frequencies["key3"]`...

```
Dictionary<string, int> frequencies = new Dictionary<string, int>();
frequencies.Add("key3", 3);
frequencies.Add("key4", 4);
frequencies.Add("key3", 5); // This raises an error

int value = frequencies["key3"];
```

Answer (score 1):

This function counts all words in a given string. In the returned dictionary exist for every found word one entry with the word as key. In the int value is stored, how many times this word was found in the string.

Answer (score 0):

It means from the `Key` to the `Value`